# Java RSA Cryptography: RSA modulus has a small prime factor

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, rsa, public-key-encryption

Trying to encrypt a message using RSA: I keep getting this error, but Im not sure what it means:

Code to generate the key

```
    generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    RSAKeyGenParameterSpec kpgSpec = new RSAKeyGenParameterSpec(2048, BigInteger.valueOf(17489));
    generator.initialize(kpgSpec);

    KeyPair keyPair = generator.generateKeyPair();

    publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
    privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
```

Code to Encrypt Messages

```
        RSAPublicKeySpec pubKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(new BigInteger(publicKeyBytes), BigInteger.valueOf(17489));

    Cipher cipher;
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PublicKey currentKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, currentKey);
    byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes());
    encrypted = bytesToString(encryptedBytes);
```

Error:

```
W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: RSA modulus has a small prime factor
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.RSAKeyParameters.validate(RSAKeyParameters.java:46)
    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.RSAKeyParameters.<init>(RSAKeyParameters.java:28)
    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.RSAUtil.generatePublicKeyParameter(RSAUtil.java:44)
    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.CipherSpi.engineInit(CipherSpi.java:288)
    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.CipherSpi.engineInit(CipherSpi.java:406)
```

Comment: Could you also post these values if you have still them? They can be interesting. Note: don't use them.

Comment: It means the key you generated using the code in the first part was not used in the code in the second part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a warning against a security catastrophe.

In RSA, we expect that the composite modulus `n` has two prime factors close to `sqrt{n}` <sup>*</sup>, otherwise, if one prime is small then one can easily factor your modulus into `n=p q` and drive your secret exponent`d` , BOOM.

Run the key-gen, again. Also, prefer to use a public exponent `3, 5, 17, 257 or 65537`. This helps to have faster calculations. You [used 17489](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=17489+to+binary) which requires 4 multiplication however `65537` requires 2 - not counting the squaring.

Also, you should call

```
Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
```

or

```
Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWITHSHA-256ANDMGF1PADDING");
```

not

```
Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
```

This is insecure, malleable, and has many attacks.

RSA is a trapdoor function. In encryption and signatures, it should never be used without proper padding.

- For encryption, [PKCS1Padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_1) and [OAEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding) can be used. OAEP is a better choice.
- For signature use [RSA-PSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_signature_scheme)

**note that** [RSA Signing is Not RSA Decryption](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs5430/2015sp/notes/rsa_sign_vs_dec.php).

**also note that:** Actually, it is not preferred to use RSA for encryption, in general, RSA is used for signatures. We combine symmetric and asymmetric encryption schemes in [Hybrid-Cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem). For example, one can use [Diffie-Hellman Key exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) to establish a common key with [forward secrecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy) so that the data can be encrypted with a symmetric encryption algorithm like AES which is much faster than any asymmetric cryptosystem. There is, also, [Key Encapsulation Mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_encapsulation) (KEM) and it is applicable to RSA, known as RSA-KEM which can be used to establish a key.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup>Keep in mind that if the primes are too close to each other then the Fermat Factoring is applicable</sub>

Answer (score 3):

To add to @kelalakas full answer, you can see the bouncy castle code that results in the exception being thrown [here](http://com.android.org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.RSAKeyParameters.validate) - the relevant logic is:

```
    // Hexadecimal value of the product of the 131 smallest odd primes from 3 to 743
private static final BigInteger SMALL_PRIMES_PRODUCT = new BigInteger(
          "8138e8a0fcf3a4e84a771d40fd305d7f4aa59306d7251de54d98af8fe95729a1f"
        + "73d893fa424cd2edc8636a6c3285e022b0e3866a565ae8108eed8591cd4fe8d2"
        + "ce86165a978d719ebf647f362d33fca29cd179fb42401cbaf3df0c614056f9c8"
        + "f3cfd51e474afb6bc6974f78db8aba8e9e517fded658591ab7502bd41849462f",
    16);

private static final BigInteger ONE = BigInteger.valueOf(1);

    if (!modulus.gcd(SMALL_PRIMES_PRODUCT).equals(ONE))
      {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("RSA modulus has a small prime factor");
      }
```

So, looking at your code, the modulus you supply (`new BigInteger(publicKeyBytes)`)  has common factor(s) with `SMALL_PRIMES_PRODUCT`.

Comment: Nice, instead of dividing 131 smallest primes to see that divides calculating GCD is more efficient.